# Aframe raycaster does not hit after changing enabled or objects properties

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, raycasting

I want my raycaster to look for intersections only when the trigger of my vive controller is pressed.
I thought to initialize the raycaster with a fake class in objects, change it to the real one `.prop` and gather the `intersectedEls`

```
let rightHand = document.getElementById('rightController');
rightHand.setAttribute('line', 'color: purple; opacity: 1;');
rightHand.setAttribute('raycaster', { showLine: true, objects: '.none' });
rightHand.setAttribute('cursor', { downEvents: ['triggerdown'], upEvents: ['triggerup'], rayOrigin: 'entity', fuse: false });

let scene = document.getElementById('scene');
scene.addEventListener('triggerdown', this.myTriggerDown);
scene.addEventListener('triggerup', this.myTriggerUp);

myTriggerDown() {
    let rightHand = document.getElementById('rightController');
    rightHand.setAttribute('raycaster', { showLine: true, objects: '.prop' });
    rightHand.components['raycaster'].refreshObjects();

    let raycaster = rightHand.components['raycaster'];
    let intersectedEls = raycaster.intersectedEls;

    if (typeof intersectedEls !== 'undefined' && intersectedEls.length > 0) {
        scene.components['resize'].enableResize(intersectedEls[0]);
    } else {
        console.log('1234 no intersections')
    }
}
myTriggerUp() {
   let rightHand = document.getElementById('rightController');
   rightHand.setAttribute('raycaster', { showLine: true, objects: '.none' });
}
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the `console.log('1234 no intersections')` message.

I tried adding the `refreshObjects()` line with no effects.
I tried toggling the `enabled` property instead of changing the `objects`, but had still the same result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

edit:

if I look for intersections in the triggerup part it works. but this is a workaround which also deprives me of using the intersected element and doing things while keeping the trigger pressed . I'd still like to know why it does not work to enable the ray/change target objects and immediately look for intersections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the `raycaster.enabled` property versus swapping to a dummy class.

The raycaster checks for intersections once per frame (or whatever the `raycaster.interval` is). On trigger down, you enable the raycaster, but you have to wait until the next frame for it to pick up intersections.

You can manually invoke intersection check via `raycaster.checkIntersections()` or run a `setTimeout` before checking.

Comment: I did try `raycaster.enabled` combined with a `setTimeout` but it still did not work.

Comment: That wasn't my suggestion. I mentioned to invoke the checkIntersections.

Comment: Oh! sorry I did not notice. `checkIntersections()` is exactly what I needed. Unfortunately I have not been able to find any info about it in the documentation. Thank you!